# Temporary Id and Id from Backend update React Native

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a functionality in React Native for creation of an item in offline mode and for this purposes is used temporary id of the item. Then when the user turns on the internet on the phone being in the screen of this newly created item, I get an error, because in online mode I send a request to the server and server returns new generated id for this item. How can I deal with this item when I have to send another request and (automatically because the phone now is in online mode) without leaving the screen, but ID changed?

Comment: Can you please better describe your use case? What request are you sending in the online mode? What is the error response? When did server get to create its own id since it shouldn't know about the offline created item yet? Can the user do some follow up operations on the item while being offline? Do you want to have other mutations such as edit/delete? Is this a collaborative app? This is a complex issue and a lot depends on your usecase & limitations.

Comment: When in online mode - I have a request to the server for creating the item in remote database. In offline mode when I create the item with temporary id it is created in local realm db and pass temporary id to the route. When the user is redirected to this item after creation in offline mode and turns on the online mode the id is changed to the real id from the server, and I have another request to the server to get the item location and this request uses temporary id, then I get the error 501 because there is no such item in the server with such id.